# Get info (url) from already enqueued styles

Tags: plugins, theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am building a theme and using Easy google fonts WordPress Plugin. I created several typography controls within Theme Customizer for Post content,Post header, Author page content, Single Post content, 404 page content...

The plugin is loading all the fonts in any page I visit. I would like to hook the style enqueue of the fonts, and return only the necessary ones, so not every selected font is called in every page, just the necessary ones.

I know how to make use of wp_dequeue_script('tt-easy-google-fonts'); I am missing a way of returning the url of the already enqueued style. When I have it then I can dequeue the script, modify the url and enqueue my new version.

So my question is how can I get the url of the already enqueued styles/scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registered styles are in the `$wp_styles` global, and registered scripts are in `$wp_scripts`. You can `var_dump` them to see their structure.

```
global $wp_scripts;
echo $wp_scripts->registered['tt-easy-google-fonts']->src;
```